# Monotouch and Hackintosh

Tags: iphone, mono, xamarin.ios, xamarin.mac, hackintosh

I have developed an app on monotouch-5.2.5 evaluation version. 
Now i want to deploy on Apple Store and to do it i have bought a full monotouch version (5.2.10) and i have installed all certificate and provisioning profile. 
When try to build my app i have the following problem:

```
mtouch exited with code 99
```

i have this configuration:

- monodevelop 2.8.6.5
- mac os x version 10.6.7 (is an HACKINTOSH)

Do could it be a incompatibity problem beetween HACKINTOSH and MonoTouch? 
...This it'll seem strange because i've develop on it without problems.

Answer (score 3):

The Xamarin.Mac / Xamarin.Ios licencing does some kind of hash of the Mac hardware to give your machine a unique ID. This locks the MonoTouch licence to your machine.
I know previously when people have changed hard drives etc. it has broken the key, this is because they use the Hard drives serial number as part of the hash. They may also use hardware MAC addresses and other IDs.

I imagine something they use in a Genuine Mac is not available in your Hackintosh.

Comment: I've read something in a forum...a user that have my same problem with same configuration he'd tried to contact mono touch customer support but when they have seen his system information they didn't give him any assistance...this seem absurd! I've installed and deploy on hackintosh an application by XCode without any problems...

Answer (score 2):

Xamarin states on their website they do not support Hackintosh. They claim it is too hard to ensure their compiler works properly in such a system, but they do not stop there. They also make it impossible to install a key on a Hackintosh or on a Mac running in a VM!

I can understand they wont provide support for issues happening in such an environment, but to force developers to buy a Mac is a bad move. Especially considering a lot of their customers choose Monotouch exactly because they are comfortable with Windows/.net already and are not eager to migrate 100% to Mac OS, it is pretty obvious many prefer to work in a VM or use their existing PC hardware.

I used the trial version in a VM without any issues whatsoever, so whatever technical issues they might be worried about seems irrelevent. So I think this is more a political issue than a technical one.

I can only hope they will change their policy, or that someone gets annoyed enough to crack their compiler so that we can all use it the way we prefer.

Comment: IMO, it's a _legal_ issue. Using a Hackintosh is a violation of Apple's license agreement, hence it Xamarin would be liable if they supported a system running on it.

Answer (score 2):

I have a Hackintosh, I just encountered the same problem, and I also can not login app store, because ethernet card not built-in, I modified the DSDT to complete built-in, it is OK.

Answer (score 1):

It is obvious that you need to contact Xamarin Support because they know better whether this is the exact problem or not. but....

A Statement in Xamarin Page demonstrated that it is impossible to use MonoDevelop/MonoTouch on Hackintosh.

I have some misunderstands that I need to know:
1. What do you mean building? (Bundle/Deploy to device/Build on Simulator)
2. Did you tried deploying to device?

I googled this issue and there are many that had this error code, but their problem was MonoTouch Activation, I think you can reactivate MonoTouch to make sure. (if you want to build on device)

But I do not attribute this error code to Hackintosh, because one of my friends-who is working with Unity (Mono) on Hackintosh, can easily build on device.

Regards,
Peyman Mortazavi

Comment: I have used MonoTouch evalution version on Hackintosh easly. Now when i try to make a Deploy on Simulator or Device in Debug or Release it give me this error. I have googled it too but i have no problem with activation because i found license's file in the specifically directory and i've tried to regenereted too without problems...Could you ask to your friend which configuration have him?!

Comment: Unity doesn't use Monotouch (which has the licence manager), it uses mono which doesn't.

Comment: Yes, you are right that monotouch differs from unity but both of them use Mono as compiler (i think) and this is the point because it is rejecting the idea that compiler is not working with Hackintosh.